# webpack5 how to know a file is newly generated (other than cached) in a plugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

webpack5 how to know a file is newly generated (other than cached) in a plugin?

Because I want to upload the new generated files to cdn, and prevent old files from uploading again, to save uploading time.

```js
class MyWebpackPlugin
  apply(compiler) {
    // Webpack 5
      compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync('my-webpack-plugin', (compilation, callback) => {
        const newGenerated = compilation.assets.filter(??) // files newly generated, (with different hash, different content)
        const cached = compilation.assets.filter(???) // the same file as previous run
      });

  }
}
```

Thanks!